# Identify locator for image in IE11 nothing doing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can someone help me to identify to how to correct the Xpath statement from the below code. At the moment when I run the code, its doing nothing i.e no error and no click action

DOM:

```
<li class="product-personal-login-new">
<a href="/safe-online-banking/safe-online-banking.page?" target="_self">
    <span class="pl-login-ornage-box">
        <img alt="" src="/assets/img/lock-icon.png">
        LOGIN
    </span>
</a>
```

Code snippet:

```
web.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/assets/img/lock-icon.png')]")).click();
```

Comment: You can try JavaScript executor..

Comment: @Ankur Singh: Thank you.. I tried and working fine however may i know the reason why its not working and cant we run without using JavaScript Executor??